# JS Auto Scroll Code Only Works as Part of HTML but Not as Separate Script in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html

Good day Masters.

I need your help with below code. The target outcome is to auto scroll the page from top to bottom then jump to top once at the bottom and repeat again and again.

The auto scroll code is working as expected in JSFiddle when ran as part of the whole HTML enclosed within "script" portion.

The problem would occur when I removed it from the whole HTML and placed it in JavaScript window in JSFiddle.

**The Code:**

```js
          var currentpos=0,alt=1,curpos1=0,curpos2=-1
          function initialize(){
          startit()
          }
          function startit(){
          const itemsElement = document.getElementById("Units");
          setInterval(
          function () {
          if (itemsElement.all)
          temp=itemsElement.body.scrollTop
          else
          temp=window.pageYOffset
          if (alt==0)
          alt=1
          else
          alt=0
          if (alt==0)
          curpos1=temp
          else
          curpos2=temp
          if (curpos1!=curpos2){
          if (itemsElement.all)
          currentpos=itemsElement.body.scrollTop+1
          else
          currentpos=window.pageYOffset+1
          window.scroll(0,currentpos)
          }
          else{
          currentpos=0
          window.scroll(0,currentpos)
          }
          }
          ,50)
          }
          window.onload=initialize
```

```html
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Auto Scroll Test Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id="Units" class="Units">
             <div>Unit 1</div>
             <div>Unit 2</div>
             <div>Unit 3</div>
             <div>Unit 4</div>
             <div>Unit 5</div>
             <div>Unit 6</div>
             <div>Unit 7</div>
             <div>Unit 8</div>
             <div>Unit 9</div>
             <div>Unit 10</div>
             <div>Unit 11</div>
             <div>Unit 12</div>
             <div>Unit 13</div>
             <div>Unit 14</div>
             <div>Unit 15</div>
             <div>Unit 16</div>
             <div>Unit 17</div>
             <div>Unit 18</div>
             <div>Unit 19</div>
             <div>Unit 20</div>
          </div>
       </body>
      
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance everyone for the help on this.

Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

In JSFiddle in JavaScript window click on options (it will be something like: `JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)` ). Then under load type change it to `No wrap - bottom of <body>`

Comment: Thank you very much @Kalimah, it's working in JSFiddle now.

My next step is to apply it to visual.ts in creating Microsoft Power BI Visual. Can't seem to make it work there.

Thanks